# How To Query Unique Users With Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Context**

In a MongoDB database, I have a collection with mail documents inside. Each document has receiver and sender fields.

**Goal**

 I want to query for one mail from each sender. In other words, I do not want two or more mail from the same sender.

**Example**

I have three documents:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    sender: John,
    receiver: Kate
}

{
    _id: 2,
    sender: John,
    receiver: Kate
}

{
    _id: 3,
    sender: Mike,
    receiver: Kate
}
```

After the query, I should end up with: (the second mail from John is not included)

```
{
    _id: 1,
    sender: John,
    receiver: Kate
}

{
    _id: 3,
    sender: Mike,
    receiver: Kate
}
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this aggregation, group by sender and push receiver to array then put receiver as first element of array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "sender": "$sender"
      },
      r: {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      sender: "$_id.sender",
      receiver: {
        $first: "$r.receiver"
      },
      description: {
        $first: "$r.description"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/mwDdL4aLneu

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just want to filter the documents not modify them. What I see in the playground is that only sender and receiver fields are left in the document. I want the entire document unmodified.